# Error checking for user input

Tags: java

I have a class that asks the user what type of truck they want. I need to know a way to do error checking so that if they enter something besides "1" or "2" that it tells them that it is an invalid option.

Here's the code:

```
public class InheritanceTUI {

    private int weight;
    private String flavors;
    private Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    private String truckType;


    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Type \"1\" if you want a generic truck" + "\n" + "Type \"2\" if you want an Ice Cream Truck");
        this.truckType = this.scan.nextLine();

        if (this.truckType.equals("1")) {
            System.out.println("You have chosen a generic truck!");
            System.out.println("Type in what weight (in pounds) you want your truck to be: ");
            String stringWeight = this.scan.nextLine();
            this.weight = Integer.parseInt(stringWeight);
            System.out.println("Your truck has a weight of " + this.weight + " pounds");
        }

        if (this.truckType.equals("2")) {
            System.out.println("You have chosen an Ice Cream Truck! " + this.truckType);
            System.out.println("Type in what weight (in pounds) that you want your ice cream truck to be: ");
            String stringWeight = this.scan.nextLine();
            this.weight = Integer.parseInt(stringWeight);
            System.out.println("You have entered a weight of " + this.weight + " pounds");
            System.out.println("What flavors do you want in your ice cream truck?");
            this.flavors = this.scan.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Your ice cream truck has a weight of " + this.weight + " pounds and contains " + this.flavors + " flavor(s)");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have missed to explain the issue

Comment: Please don't edit the post eliminating the original question, it might be useful for someone else. Just accept the best answer and leave the post as it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check for the condition at the beginning:

```
if (!"1".equals(truckType) && !"2".equals(truckType)) {
    // it's an invalid option, do something about it
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use switch/case, and handle the invalid option in the default branch

Some additional information: you can switch on Strings from Java SE 7 only. Up till Java SE 6 you can e.g. use Integer.parseInt(truckType) to convert your String values to int and do the switch on that afterwards

Answer (score 1):

you can use switch case for this. or you should place else condition after if condition.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (this.truckType.equals("1")) {
       //Code
    }
  else if (this.truckType.equals("2")) {
       //Code
    }
else {
    System.out.println("Invalid option");
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your best option would be to use a switch case